# JPA2/Hibernate Criteria or CriteriaQuery for Postgres JSON type

Tags: json, hibernate, postgresql, jpa-2.0

I have a PostgreSQL database with JSON fields. I would like to construct a query which restricts results by JSON expressions. I can formulate this query in psql without problem:

```
select * from mytable where relation_id=100 AND CAST(jsonField->'key' AS float) >= 10.0;
```

This query combines a normal column and a JSON column.

I have no idea how to start this in Hibernate using Criteria or Criteria query. I could, in theory, use HSQL language, but I am almost certain that will fail when it comes to the JSON column.

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this?

Comment: You'll have to use native queries unless you're willing to write a Hibernate extension that adds the JSON types and operators to the Criteria API and/or HQL. That's the price you pay for using an ORM - it's convenient until you want to do anything interesting and outside the lowest-common-denominator of database functionality.

Comment: Any news about this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that is to write a custom `SQLFunction` for the `CAST(jsonField->'key' AS float)` expression and then use that in JPQL.

```
public String render(Type firstArgumentType, List args, SessionFactoryImplementor factory) throws QueryException {
    return "CAST(" + args.get(0).toString() + "->'" + args.get(1).toString() + "' AS float)";
}
```

Register in the dialect with `registerFunction("json_float", new JsonFloatFunction())` and use it in the query like

```
SELECT o FROM MyTable o WHERE o.relation.id = 100 AND JSON_FLOAT(o.jsonField, 'key') >= 10.0
```